# I installed Ubuntu 22.04. Should I use it as is or is it better to add GNOME desktop environment to it?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, desktop-environments

I installed Ubuntu 22.04. Should I use it as it is, or is it better to add GNOME desktop environment to it? If so, what version of GNOME should I use?

A guy in a computer shop gave me a USB flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04. I thought it was the desktop version, but apparently it is not because I do not have GNOME desktop installed. What should I do, keep the Ubuntu version that I have without GNOME or reinstall the desktop version that comes with GNOME?

Comment: Have you installed it? Do you trust that guy downloaded an up to date and genuine unmodified image ... If yes, then Desktop related packages are in one meta package that you can simply install with `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` and that should evolve your system to GUI DE ... But I would go with @karel's answer below.

Comment: How do you know you don't have GNOME installed?

Comment: Have you used Gnome? I have used Gnome and the Ubuntu version. I prefer the Ubuntu version easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu uses GNOME desktop environment with a modified Ubuntu theme by default. If your Ubuntu has the characteristic purple wallpaper with an animal picture on it, then it already has GNOME desktop environment installed and you can continue to use it without installing any other desktop environment.

You haven't used Ubuntu for long enough to have many personal files stored on the disk. If you don't already have the default GNOME desktop environment installed, your best bet is to download Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 (the latest Long Term Support version) from the official Ubuntu website, make a bootable Ubuntu USB using the built-in Startup Disk Creator app in Ubuntu, boot the Ubuntu installation USB, and at the *Installation type* screen select *Erase disk and install Ubuntu*. This option will delete any files on the disk  and install Ubuntu 22.04 on the entire disk. Installing Ubuntu 22.04 will take a bit less than a half hour, well worth the time spent because your new installation of Ubuntu 22.04 will be easier to maintain than your existing Ubuntu would be if you added a replacement GNOME desktop environment to it.